# Showing progress control in custom datasource

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro

I'm trying create my own datasource. I'm following [the sample code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-custom-data-4dcfb128#content).

However I'm not able to find a way to show the progress controls. I search the entire sample code. I couldn't any progress control.

Basically, I dont know how I will know the datasource has completed fetching data. Could any provide me a hint/sample?

Answer (score 0):

The progress control markup is as follows:

```
<progress></progress> or <progress class='win-ring'></progress>
```

Your second question about knowing when the data has been successfully retrieved is a perfect job for a [promise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx).